# How to have folders in an Amazon S3 bucket use the same file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an Amazon S3 bucket to host a static website. I have a folder called "terms-of-use/" inside that folder, I have folders for the translations example: en/, es/, bs/, bg/, fr/ and so on.

As of right now I have a index.html file in each folder. Would it be possible to have all the folders use a single index.html file? and keep the url structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. You have to explain exactly what you want to do and what is wrong with the current file structure.

Answer (score 1):

In every index.html link to a generic/general index file which you maintain somewhere on S3. This way you will make changes in one place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).